# How to combine style properties in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
const styles = theme => (
  console.log('theme',theme), {

    layoutHeader : {
      height: 320,
      minHeight: 320,
      background: "url('/assets/images/backgrounds/dark-material-bg.jpg') no-repeat",
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
      color: '#fff',
      [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
        height: 240,
        minHeight: 240
      }
    }
  }
);

class ProfilePage extends Component {
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <PageSimple
        classes={{header : classes.layoutHeader}}
    )
  }
}
```

I want to change the background after the page is loaded.

How can I do, for example something like this:

```
const newStyle = styles([
  classes.layoutHeader,
  {background: this.props.backgroundimageurl}
]);

classes={{ header : newStyle }}
```

Is this possible? I tried this but it didn't work, could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like Object.assign.A little example with JSX here:

```
const layoutHeader = {
  ...
}
const showStyle = {
  background: 'red'
}
const bineStyle = Object.assign(layoutHeader,showStyle)
```

Comment: error does not, but does not work  showStyle properties

Comment: Does "classes" works well?We usually use style or className.@DanyNounkeu

Comment: yes classes i work normally, layoutHeader run single, 
in this case run
const bineStyle = Object.assign(hiddenStyle,showStyle)
but ,showStyle porperties dont work

Comment: This works fine for me.Could you share the code after you changed?@DanyNounkeu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in an object as styling to your component, you simply need to use the style attribute, and not as a class

```
<Component style={this.styleObject} />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spread operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) of ES seem like a cleaner approach to me.

```
const layoutHeader = {
  ...
}
const showStyle = {
  background: 'red'
}
const combo = { ...hiddenStyle, ...showStyle }
```

Note: The keys will be overwritten with a serial order (e.g. last write wins)